# How to add side panel when using cached pages in Framework7?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, html-framework-7

I'm working with cached pages, I wrote all pages in a single file index.html.

How to add the side panel to a particular page?

**index.html**

```
<body>
<div class="statusbar-overlay"></div>
<div class="views">
  <div class="view view-main">
    <!-- Navbar -->
    <div class="navbar no-border">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="center sliding">Welcome to Page</div>
        <div class="right"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-inner cached" data-page="detailsPage">
        <div class="left sliding">
          <a href="index" class="link back">
            <i class="icon icon-back"></i><span>Back</span>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="center sliding">Detail page</div>
        <div class="right"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-inner cached" data-page="loginPage">
        <div class="left sliding">
          <a href="index" class="link back">
            <i class="icon icon-back"></i><span>Back</span>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="center sliding">Login</div>
        <div class="right"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-inner cached" data-page="registerPage">
        <div class="left sliding">
          <a href="index" class="link back">
            <i class="icon icon-back"></i><span>Back</span>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="center sliding">Register</div>
        <div class="right"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="navbar-inner cached" data-page="welcome">
        <div class="left sliding">
          <!-- <a href="index" class="link back">
            <i class="icon icon-back"></i><span>Back</span>
          </a> -->
        </div>
        <div class="center sliding">Realmilk</div>
        <div class="right"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Pages -->
    <div class="pages navbar-through toolbar-through">

      <!-- Page 1 -->
      <div data-page="index" class="page" ng-controller="IndexPageController">
        <!-- Page content-->
        <div class="page-content">
          <a href="#loginPage" class="button button-big button-round">Realmilk Login</a>
          <a href="#registerPage" class="button button-big button-round">Register Here</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Page 2 -->
      <div data-page="detailsPage" class="page cached" ng-controller="DetailPageController">
        <!-- Page content-->
        <div class="page-content">
          This is page 2
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Welcome Page-->
      <div data-page="welcome" class="page cached" ng-controller="WelcomePageController">
        <!-- Page content-->
        <div class="page-content">
          <div class="card">
              <div class="card-content">
                <div class="card-content-inner">Welcome to the Realmilk :: {{user_info.firstName}}</div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <style>
            .demo-card-header-pic .card-header {
              height: 40vw;
              background-size: cover;
              background-position: center;
            }
          </style>

          <div class="card demo-card-header-pic">
            <div style="background-image:url(http://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2015/googles-new-logo-5078286822539264.3-hp2x.gif)" valign="bottom" class="card-header color-white no-border">Journey To Mountains</div>
            <div class="card-content">
              <div class="card-content-inner">
                <p class="color-gray">Enrolled on January 21, 2015</p>
                <p>Molabanti Dairy farm is RealMilk certified cattle farm.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
              <a href="#" class="link">Like</a>
              <a href="#" class="link">Read more</a>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Login Page -->
      <div data-page="loginPage" class="page cached" ng-controller="LoginPageController">
        <!-- Page content-->
        <div class="page-content">
          <form id="login-form" class="list-block">
            <div class="item-content">
              <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title label">Email</div>
                <div class="item-input">
                  <input type="email" name="emailId" id="emailId" placeholder="Enter Email" ng-model="user.emailId">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item-content">
              <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title label">Password</div>
                <div class="item-input">
                  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter Password" ng-model="user.password">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>

          <div class="content-block">
            <p><a href="#" class="button button-round active" ng-click="signIn(user)">Sign In</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Registration Page -->
      <div data-page="registerPage" class="page cached" ng-controller="RegisterPageController">
        <!-- Page content-->
        <div class="page-content">
          <form id="registration-form" class="list-block">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <div class="item-content">
                  <div class="item-media"><i class="icon f7-icons">persons</i></div>
                  <div class="item-inner">
                    <!-- <div class="item-title label">Gender</div> -->
                    <div class="item-input">
                      <select id="boom" name="type" ng-model="user.type">
                        <option value="Retailer">Consumer</option>
                        <option value="Dairyfarm">Farmer</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
              <!-- Text inputs -->
              <li>
                <div class="item-content">
                  <div class="item-media"><i class="icon f7-icons">person</i></div>
                  <div class="item-inner">
                    <!-- <div class="item-title label">First Name</div> -->
                    <div class="item-input">
                      <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First name" ng-model="user.first_name">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
              <!-- Text inputs -->
              <li>
                <div class="item-content">
                  <div class="item-media"><i class="icon f7-icons">person</i></div>
                  <div class="item-inner">
                    <!-- <div class="item-title label">Last Name</div> -->
                    <div class="item-input">
                      <input type="text" placeholder="Last name">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div class="item-content">
                  <div class="item-media"><i class="icon f7-icons">phone</i></div>
                  <div class="item-inner">
                    <!-- <div class="item-title label">Phone</div> -->
                    <div class="item-input">
                      <input type="tel" id="phone" name="primary_mobile_number" placeholder="Phone" ng-model="user.primary_mobile_number"/>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div class="item-content">
                  <div class="item-media"><i class="icon f7-icons">email</i></div>
                  <div class="item-inner">
                    <!-- <div class="item-title label">Email</div> -->
                    <div class="item-input">
                      <input type="email" name="email_id" id="email_id" placeholder="Enter Email" ng-model="user.email_id">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div class="item-content">
                  <div class="item-media"><i class="icon f7-icons">lock</i></div>
                  <div class="item-inner">
                    <!-- <div class="item-title label">Password</div> -->
                    <div class="item-input">
                      <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="user.password"/>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div class="item-content">
                  <div class="item-media"><i class="icon f7-icons">lock</i></div>
                  <div class="item-inner">
                    <!-- <div class="item-title label">Password</div> -->
                    <div class="item-input">
                      <input type="password" id="confirmpassword" name="confirmpassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" ng-model="user.confirmpassword"/>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </form>
          <div class="content-block">
            <p><a href="#" class="button button-round active" ng-click="registerUser(user)">Register</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to what I see from the [documentation](http://framework7.io/docs/side-panels.html).

Add this html syntax after: 
 `<div class="statusbar-overlay"></div>` 
 or before: 
`<div class="views">...</div>`.

**CODE SYNTAX:**

```
<div class="panel-overlay"></div>
<div class="panel panel-left panel-reveal">
  <div class="content-block">
    <p>Left Panel content here</p>
    <p><a href="#" class="close-panel">Close me</a></p>
    <p><a href="#" data-panel="right" class="open-panel">Open Right Panel</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Ok, now when you have panels in your App, you need to know how to open/close them:**

- To open panel we need to add "open-panel" class to any HTML element (prefered to link)
- To close panel we need to add "close-panel" class to any HTML element (prefered to link)
- If you have two panels in app, such link will open/close Left panel by default
- If you want to specify which panel should opened/closed, then it could be done via additional data-panel="left" attribute on this HTML element

**Open Panels With Swipe**

To make this feature works you need to enable it on App initialization by passing related parameter:

```
var myApp = new Framework7({
    swipePanel: 'left'
});
```

Comment: Now, What I need is how to add side panel icon on particular page status-bar?